# Commercial vs Open source CMS and load balancing

Tags: open-source, content-management-system, load-balancing

I need an open source alternative to something like Sitefinity where load balancing is vitally important for a client's site.

Upon doing a quick Google search it looks like Joomla is able to handle load balancing but I also wanted to find out if anyone else knows of a rock solid open source CMS capable of handling high traffic in a load balanced scenario.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For scaling CMS sites, it's often a case of compatibility with 3rd party tools.

My recent experience has been with Drupal, but the tools are the same for other *AMP based tools (ie. PHP/Apache/MySQL based), like most open source CMS's are.

The real key thing to determine for you will be the compatibility of each CMS with these standard tools for getting the scalability happening.  That is almost more important than the  specific scalability features of the CMS itself, which are pretty much the same in most modern CMS's (aggressive caching and so on).

The typical pieces of the puzzle for Linux are the following.  You should evaluate which of these pieces matter to you and which will work with the CMS you choose.

- Varnish: This HTTP reverse proxy will sit in front of your main webserver and efficiently serve up anonymous page requests where it can.  If you have a site with lots of anonymous (not logged in) traffic, then Varnish will pretty much give you the same performance you'd get if your site was static HTML pages.   The catch: Your CMS must cooperate with Varnish, either through an add-on module or direct knowledge of how to behave behind one of these proxies.  Anonymous pages must be served up without any unique cookies on them, or Varnish cannot do its thing.
- Memcached: This in-memory object cache is used as an alternative to cache tables in your SQL database.  As we all know, memory access is 1000 times faster than disk access, so it stands to reason that if you keep these cached bits in memory, instead of having to use the database and spin the disks to run queries.. that your site will be very fast.   It also stands to reason you need enough RAM to hold extra copies of stuff in memory.
- Caching in the CMS:  All modern CMS's try do to this as well as they can, it's the key to performance.  The achilles heel of all modern CMS's is that you can't really cache logged in data very well (ie. a dashboard that has different stuff to say for each user).  So if your users are all logged in, say for a community site or something, then neither this nor the two items above is going to help all that much.
- CDN:  When CMS people throw around "use a CDN" they mean a couple things.  One is what it sounds like, host stuff like static files on a content delivery network provided by Google or Amazon or someone, and things will load faster.  But the other thing it means is to set up multiple parallel DNS names to load content off.  Your browser will load 6 things at once max from a single domain.  If you make:  a.example.com, b.example.com, c.example.com, d.example.com, e.example.com, and then if your CMS supports this CDN technique, then a browser could download 30 things at once instead of 6 - it could grab 6 items (.css files, .js files, images, whatever) off each of a., b., c., d., and e.example.com.  This speeds sites up, but again your CMS has to support it (built-in or through some kind of add on module)
- Database replication?   This is always prickly if you are talking about doing it in MySQL.  Regardless of database, replication is a tough problem to solve, especially if it has to be 2-way replication (each side has to read and write).    If you do everything above perfectly, and buy the best hardware you can, and stick the database on its own high performance server with no other services on it, and a nice fast raid-10 array say with 6 disks to get yourself really awesome disk performance........ then you could probably go a long way with a single master database.  (it would definitely be a wise idea to replicate to a backup machine if you had all your eggs in one basket like that).  Anyway, by this point you are in standard database replication land...   Your CMS might support having multiple database entries, but it's largely more a question of "how do you cluster" rather than "what CMS are you clustering".  I'd be surprised if any of the modern alternatives wouldn't allow you to set more than one database hostname for clustering, and you could always do it in DNS by round-robin'ing the hostname of your DNS server.  Again though, not related to your choice of CMS really.

And to end this all of, and to answer your question, I of course recommend Drupal as a rock solid scalable CMS.  Is it easy to scale it so it runs a site like examiner.com or whitehouse.gov or a university site with hundreds if not thousands of sub sites and millions of nodes?  Heck no!  Nor will that challenge be easy in any CMS you choose.. but you should also be able to choose any modern popular CMS and make it work fast, if you address all of the above.

Comment: Wow! This is extensive...thank you Faken :) Extremely useful!

Comment: If I only could upvote more than one time.Great elaboration

Answer (score 1):

Plone has a very good loadbalancing story:

http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/deployment/

http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/deployment/stack.html#load-balancing

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) in a clustered setup with rather high loads. Works fine. We have noticed minor issues with lucene index synchonization though- it may take a minute or two for it to replicate through all nodes.

The GA version is open source. They also provide extensive documentation and training.

Comment: Thanks Kostja. I will look into this. If there are others, please keep it coming.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion and some might not agree with it, but the majority of medium to enterprise content management systems (both open source and commercial) offer load balancing functionality. The question is how efficient and scalable is their solution. For example, Sitefinity offers load balancing where each server in a web farm must be aware of other servers. For example, if I have 20 servers in a web farm, then I have to configure each server and make sure it's aware of other servers. This is a real pain, but it's still a "load balancing" feature. What I'm trying to say is make sure that you investigate on how the load balancing works in a certain CMS before you decide to use that CMS.

Comment: Thanks CodeRush! I will be sure to look into this!